# PHP replace string

Tags: php, string

```
$string = 'http://site.com/category/1/news/2134/'; // '1' is dynamic
```

**How can I change `1` to any number I want?**

Can't call parts of the string, its just a text-like variable.

It can be done with some true regex.

Comment: Please define the problem in more detail. Will the number always be prefixed by "category"? Will it always be the 2nd member of the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('~(?<=category/)[0-9]+(?=/news)~', '56', $string);
```

This replaces the number by 56.

This approach uses a regex with [assertions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = explode('/',$string);
$array[4] = '666';
$string = implode('/',$array);
```

[edit]
@People downvoting, what seems to be the problem with this approach?

Comment: That's pretty fragile for any string-processing task.  It's not even going to break in a convincing way if the input is not well-formed.

Answer (score 2):

Without more information, my best guess at your problem is :

```
<?php
$string = 'http://site.com/category/' . $yourNumberHere . '/news/2134/';
?>
```