# Search a string for keywords and add HTML tags around word

Tags: php

I not new to programming but I am new to PHP. I need to write a function that takes in a string, checks it against a known list of key words and if those key words are found, then it adds HTML tags around that word, while leaving the rest of the string intact. I really don't know a lot of PHP but here's the shell I have

```
function check_me($text)
{
    $result=$text;
    return $result;
}
```

How can I check the string `$text` for key words and wrap HTML tags around them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP replace string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636339/php-replace-string)

Comment: Where you will store keywords (database, .txt file, something else)?

Comment: @nevermind I'm open to suggestions. I'm assuming I can just store them in an array within the same page? It's a known set of keywords, so it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: http://www.php.net/explode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have all the keyworks setup in an array, or read them from a file into an array you can simply use the **str_replace** function.

```
$keywords = array(
    "dog",
    "cat",
    "bunny"
    );
$string = "The cat is sleeping on the couch";
$string = str_replace($keywords, "elephant", $string);
//Outputs "The elephant is sleeping on the couch"
```

Read more on the PHP Manual for [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace).